# Problme with HTML 5 validations

Tags: html, list, validation, html-lists

I try to write HTML5 valid code for my webpage, but when I use the W3 Validator, I get an error message like this:

`Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`

What did I do wrong and how can I solve the problem?  Here is my code:

```
<ul class="ul_main">
  <li>INFORMÁCIÓK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ FEJLESZTŐ / KIADÓ</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">FEJLESZTŐK / KIADÓK</li>
  </ul>
  <li>KATEGÓRIÁK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ KATEGÓRIA</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">KATEGÓRIÁK</li>
  </ul>
  <li>PLATFORMOK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ PLATFORM</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">PLATFORMOK</li>
  </ul>
  <li>JÁTÉKOK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ ALAPINFORMÁCIÓ</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ALAPINFORMÁCIÓK</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ JÁTÉK</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">JÁTÉKOK</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ GALÉRIA</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">GALÉRIÁK</li>
  </ul>
  <li>BLOGOK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ BLOG</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">BLOGOK</li>
  </ul>
  <li>BEÁLLÍTÁSOK</li>
  <ul class="ul_sub">
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ SABLON</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">SABLONOK</li>
    <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">RENDSZER</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only tag allowed as a child to `<ul>` is an `<li>` element. You can put in your sub-`<ul>` as children of the respective `<li>` elements.

So restructure your HTML like this:

```
<ul class="ul_main">
  <li>INFORMÁCIÓK
    <ul class="ul_sub">
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ FEJLESZTŐ / KIADÓ</li>
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">FEJLESZTŐK / KIADÓK</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>KATEGÓRIÁK
    <ul class="ul_sub">
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ KATEGÓRIA</li>
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">KATEGÓRIÁK</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1):

An `ul` element can not contain an `ul` element as child, you have to put a `li` between, e.g.

**Do:**

```
<ul>
    <li><ul><!-- more <li> --></ul></li>
     <!-- go on with <li>s -->
</ul>
```

**Do not:**

```
<ul>
    <ul><!-- more <li> --></ul>
     <!-- go on with <li>s -->
</ul>
```

**In your case:**

```
<ul class="ul_main">
  <li>INFORMÁCIÓK
    <ul class="ul_sub">
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">ÚJ FEJLESZTŐ / KIADÓ</li>
      <li><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="" title="">FEJLESZTŐK / KIADÓK</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
```